# Want to create a outbound conference call using twilio javascript SDK

Tags: twilio, conference

I made one web application, which allow user to call from a browser with the help of twilio. Now i want to make a outbound conference call using twilio. I want to add a third person in my conference. I read the articles regarding conference in twilio, but didn't got the idea. Any one help me for this problem. Thank you in advance.

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$twilio = new Client($TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, $TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
$Psid = $twilio->conferences($ConferenceRoom,['conferenceStatusCallbackEvent' => 'start end join leave mute hold','conferenceStatusCallback' => 'statuscallbackurl','conferenceStatusCallbackMethod'=>'POST'])
                        ->participants
                        ->create("Mytwilionumber",$Participantnumber);
```

I tried the above code, which allows to add multiple participants in a conference. Which is working perfectly. But now i want to get the particular conference recordings and it's status callback, i tried above method for status callback but it's not working. Any solution for that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you made a conference call? What code are you using so far?

Comment: I updated my question, please check it. Thank you for reply.